# Cant draw two items to Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, graphics2d

I cant Draw two items( there will be more) to a Jframe, im trying to make a landscape, but the item painted last overwrites anything before it.

Main:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class TheComponets extends JComponent {




    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setTitle("A house on the water!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        House home = new House();
        Sun sun = new Sun();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
        frame.add(home);
        frame.add(sun);



    }




}
```

House class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

// Program to draw a house
public class House extends JComponent
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        // Draw the roof
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        int xs[] = {100,160,220};
        int ys[] = {100,50,100};
        Polygon poly=new Polygon(xs,ys,3);
        g.fillPolygon(poly);

        // Draw the body of house
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(100,100,120,120);

        // draw the door
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(145,160,30,60);


    }
}
```

Sun class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sun extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        // draw sun
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(500, 0, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

I want the house and the sun to show up in the Jframe, but as of now it will only show the last frame.add() object. I have only been programming for two months and dont know much about Swing and awt. Please try to keep that in mind when answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this, is that a `JFrame` uses a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) by default. When you `frame.add(component)` without any constraints, the component will be added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. So, no matter how many components you will add without constraints, borderlayout will override the older since all of them are being added to `CENTER`.

The solution would be either to choose where you want your components to be added:

```
frame.add(home,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(sun,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

either to change the layout of your container (the JFrame in your case):

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.add(home);
frame.add(sun);
```

Worth to read: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

**Finally**, do not `@Override` `paint()` method. `@Override` `paintComponent()` method instead.

Comment: Im trying to use a GridLayout, but now my Jframe does not pop up at all, i've made changes to the classes above to reflect the changes i made based on your answer. Any idea why the frame is not showing?

Comment: @Mr.Pat Did you `frame.setVisiblue(true);` ?

Comment: Yikes, that's embarrassing. It was in the initial program, but I guess i deleted it when i made changes. Its working now! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

To Add multiple components on JFrame, need to set layout from  Layout manager. it can be FlowLayout or Gridlayout or BorderLayout....

In your case,it add Last component only because JFrame's default layout is BoderLayout and can add component

frame.add(home, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

you have PAGE_START, PAGE_END, LINE_START, LINE_END, CENTER position to add component. so add second component to other position or change layout  of frame using

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

Comment: `System.out.println(new JFrame("").getLayout().getClass());` prints `class java.awt.BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

When you use individual panels for custom painting then your painting will be done in 2D since components are positioned in 2D space based on the layout manager used.

> im trying to make a landscape,

Then keep all you custom painting in a single class.

First you paint the background. Then you paint the sun, then the house etc.

You will now have full control over the order in which items are painted.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I guess im painting a landscape where the user defines what they see, so in some there will be a boat with a lake and in others there will be trees. Your right, I just did not explain it clearly.